# No @QueryParam/@RequestParam configuration for parameter 'username'

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

Help me please, i create my own annotations extending fosrestbundle annotation, to have url in this format users?param=...&param2=...
my annotation is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace REST\UserBundle\Annotations;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Param;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"CLASS", "METHOD"})
 */
class CustomParam extends Param 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getValue(Request $request, $default = null)
    {
        return $request->request->has($this->getKey())
            ? $request->request->get($this->getKey(), $default)
            : $request->query->get($this->getKey(), $default);
     }
}
```

my controller is as following:

```
       /**
 * Create a User from the submitted data.<br/>
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true,
 *   description = "Creates a new user from the submitted data.",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     200 = "Returned when successful",
 *     400 = "Returned when the form has errors"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher Paramfetcher
 *
 * @CustomParam(name="username", value="foufou" ,nullable=false, strict=true, description="Username.")
 * @CustomParam(name="email", value="foufou@gmail.com", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Email.")
 * @CustomParam(name="password", value="foufou", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Password.")
 * @CustomParam(name="plainPassword", value="foufou", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Plain Password.")
 * @CustomParam(name="company_name", value="ffff", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Company.")
 * @CustomParam(name="adress_zip", value="papappa", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Zip.")
 * @CustomParam(name="adress_name", value="rue hhh",nullable=false, strict=true, description="Adress.")
 * @CustomParam(name="adress_city", value="paris",nullable=false, strict=true, description="City.")
 * @CustomParam(name="adress_country", value="France", nullable=false, strict=true, description="Country.")   
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function postUserAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{

    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();


    $user->setUsername($paramFetcher->get('username'));
    $user->setEmail($paramFetcher->get('email'));
    $user->setPassword($paramFetcher->get('password'));
    $user->setPlainPassword($paramFetcher->get('plainPassword'));
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $user->addRole('ROLE_API');
        $adress = new Adress();
        $adress->setAdress($paramFetcher->get('adress_name'));
        $adress->setCity($paramFetcher->get('adress_city'));
        $adress->setZip($paramFetcher->get('adress_zip'));
        $adress->setCountry($paramFetcher->get('adress_country'));
        $company = new Company();
        $company->setName($paramFetcher->get('company_name'));
    $user->setAdress($adress);
    $user->setCompany($company);

    $view = View::create();

    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user, array('Registration'));

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        $view->setData($user)->setStatusCode(200);
        return $view;
    } else {
        $view = $this->getErrorsView($errors);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

but i get this error, No @QueryParam/@RequestParam configuration for parameter 'username'